Wiring ethernet cable in condo. What standard to use for RJ45 connector for existing wiring?
I just moved in to a new condo. And one of the things I have in this condo is what I'm guessing is ethernet in every room. I counted 4 female connectors and I have 4 purple wires just hanging out my wall. I want to crimp an RJ45 connector to those wires and have ethernet in my whole condo.
The female jacks around my apartment look like this
Ethernet jack
So the next thing I did is open one up to see how they wired it up. From what I understand is there are two standards T-568A and B so I should look and see what standard was used and crimp it that way on the other end, right?
So I open it up and I don't recognize any standard from this:
wiring in the back
The colors don't seem to match either standard + it doesn't seem to follow the 1/2, 3/6, 4/5, 7/8 pin layout I see everywhere. From the pic it looks like it is from left to right: white/blue, blue, white/orange, orange, ?, green, white/brown?, brown
Do I need to rewire this? Is it possible that the connector does some internal rewiring or am I looking at this somehow wrong? Do the order of the colors matter?
I'm in Europe if that makes a difference.

Colors don’t really matter as long as both ends are identical including the cable you connect to the port

Those could also be phone connectors, RJ-11 plugs can fit inside RJ-45 ports. You should talk with your apartment manager about what those are, where the cables run to, and what sorts of things they expect to be connected to them.


it doesn't seem to follow the 1/2, 3/6, 4/5, 7/8 pin layout I see everywhere

The wiring pins at the back of RJ45 sockets don't necessarily correspond 1:1 to the jacks – often they're arranged to keep the twisted-pairs together for more convenient wiring (to avoid people splitting up pairs for the sake of saving some time), and the socket internally redistributes them in the correct order.
So your photo seems fairly normal, although to know for sure you'd need to open it up and look at the indications inside.

Do the order of the colors matter?

What actually matters is that the overall layout of the twisted-pairs must remain the same, i.e. you cannot split pins that are expected to be in the same pair (as the reliability of Ethernet relies on pairs being twisted together). So it's fine to swap blue/blue-stripe with green/green-stripe, but never green/yellow-stripe or such.
Aside from that requirement, it doesn't matter which pair gets which color. Of course, both ends of a single cable still need to match¹, and following one of the standard color assignments will make life much easier. The colors don't need to match across the entire length – you can have wall jacks wired using one standard and patch cables using another.
¹ Though often Gigabit Ethernet equipment can even figure out swapped pairs (it takes longer for the connection to come up but then it works), but it's best to never do that either.
